# how to check date entered by user in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a function that takes as parameter the id of my input tag and checks the following cases:
1 - The date entered must be in the future (The date entered cannot be in the past)
2 - The date entered must not be greater than 6 months

this is my code

```
<body>
<h1>Check user date value</h1>
  a: <input type="date" name="dateResName" id="dateResId" required/>
  <input type ="button" value="Check Date User" onclick= "checkUserDate(document.getElementById('dateResId').value);" >

<script>
  function checkUserDate(dtUser) {
    var  today = new Date();
    var d = new Date(dtUser);
    var m = d.getMonth();
    var sixMonthAfterToday = new Date(now).setMonth(now.getMonth() + 6);
    var dtUserSixMonthAfter = d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 6);
    if(dtUserSixMonthAfter > sixMonthAfterToday) {
    alert("The date entered must not be greater than 6 months");
    }
    
    if(true) {
    alert("The date entered cannot be in the past");
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
```

how can I check if the date cannot be in the past and not six month greater it ?

Comment: you can try to convert both dates to milliseconds and compere them to see if date is in future. since 6 month can be converted to milliseconds too, this method just might work